# How to convert RGB values to Intensity

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, c++

I made an arduino color sensor with tcs3200 and arduino uno. I have coded the arduino to find the RGB values when I place the color paper below the sensor. How can I derive the intensity using the RGB values.

Comment: How do you define "intensity"?

Answer (score 2):

I remember a formula that calculated luminance (perceived brightness) using simple weights applied to the red, green, and blue values in a light source.

This formula allows for the fact that the human eye is most sensitive to green light and least sensitive to blue light.

The Wiki article on HSV/HSL has these different weightings for R,G, and B. (In all of the following, `Y'` is the computed brightness value.)

```
Y' = 0.2989 • R + 0.5870 • G + 0.1140 • B
Y' = 0.2120 • R + 0.7010 • G + 0.0870 • B
Y' = 0.2126 • R + 0.7152 • G + 0.0722 • B
Y' = 0.2627 • R + 0.6780 • G + 0.0593 • B
```

All of them weigh green more than the other 2. I didn't read the article closely enough to understand the different weightings of the different formulas. Perhaps they convert colors using different color models like Adobe RGB and sRGB.

See the link at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to have a formula from the RGB values to intensity.
Also, there is intensity that can be measured with an intensity meter/sensor, but what people (humans, or each individual) consider more intensity (perceived intensity) is not fully related.

However, some things I found when I had a similar problem:

- Typically a LED value of 0 is OFF, 1 is shining a little and 255 a lot. However, the difference in (perceived) intensity between value 1 and 10 is much higher than between e.g. 100 and 255.
- Also, each LED color has a different intensity, e.g. red seems more bright than blue or green, with the same R, G or B value for the DMX lights I have, as can be read from the remarks from Duncan C and Majenko below, red is less bright than others.
- Also, it depends on the physical device probably (it could have an internal algorithm to convert an RGB value to some power driven to the LED(s)).

What you can do is measure for each value and color the intensity with an intensity meter or sensor.
Or, in case you are more interested in the perceived intensity, manually check two LEDs with values to and create your own intensity algorithm.

I ended up having 3 arrays (for R, G, B), having for each value from 0-255 an 'intensity' value. I did it partly by measuring, partly by manually checking.

Comment: Red seems more bright?!? That doesn't sound right. The human visual system is most sensitive to green light. Red and blue wavelengths are much less visible at the same intensity.

Comment: Red is used for night-time illumination as the eyes are less sensitive to it and doesn't cause the irises to contract ruining your night vision. Green is used for night vision because the eyes are more sensitive to it.

Comment: Maybe 'my' Chinese DMX light has already some kind of algorithm inside because red is more bright than others, but in general it is not. I will change my answer

Comment: @Majenko: red is used for night-time illumination because the L cone cells in the retina are sensitive to it, while the rods are not. The rods are responsible for night vision and, since the can't see the red light, that light doesn't inhibit them.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers That's probably more down to lensing than brightness.

Comment: @EdgarBonet too technical...

Comment: @Majenko Could be true ... anyway I made these RGB tables to make the brightness (according to me) better.